# How to find home router's port number?

Tags: ip, router, port

I can't access my router. I have the IP, but I don't know the port number, and I can't access it without it.

1. If anyone knows a way to override, and access without port number, please say.
2. Up till now I was (and am) accessing router by reading up the port number in 'Windows File Explorer' > 'Network' > 'Network Infrastructure' section, but the problem is that section is not always there. It is randomly present in the 'Network' screen. 'Computer', and other devices are always there, but 'Network Infrastructure' section is simply random. How do I get it to always show up?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried going to `192.168.1.1` in the browser? Or `192.168.1.1:24576` as shown in the screenshot?

Comment: No, this is the old screenshot. I can't access with just 192.168.1.1 ever. Anc I can't access with 192.168.1.1:24576 anymore. I have to get the current port number.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://tplinkwifi.net or as ceejay recommended http://192.168.1.1 also [Check this](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/87/)

Answer (score -1):

Could you enter netstat -a in command prompt? When you see your IP address, the router's IP and port number should be to the right in the foreign address column.

Comment: Nope, there is no that port. I've even managed to get Netowork Infrastructure to show up last week, and connected to router ( I think it was port 13xxx something) but there was not that port engaged anywhere on netstat list.